# Going crazy trying to change android theme on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

please can someone help me.

I have been trying for four days to get the default orange color of a highlighted listview item to change to anything else.

I have tried to set the theme of my project to the Holo.Light one as well but can't get it right no matter what I do.

I've tried setting it in the MainActivity like this

```
 [Activity(Label = "Proj", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

I've tried setting it in the AndroidManifest file like this:

```
<application android:label="com.proj.app" android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"></application>
```

I've tried messing with the builds and set them to the highest possible (9 & 8.1) and tried setting the minsdk and targetsdks to the latests.

Nothing is working. Please can someone help me.

I've also tried implementing custom renderers but can't get those right either.

All I want to do is make it that the highlighted row of the below listview not be orange.

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="StudentsView" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default">
                    <ListView.Header>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                            <Image Source="studentsicon.png" Margin="6,10,6,10" ></Image>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="#222222">
                                <Label Text="Select a student" FontSize="16" TextColor="White"></Label>
                            </Frame>
                            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="actStudents" IsVisible="False" IsRunning="False" Color="#DF304F" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ListView.Header>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="#222222" CornerRadius="0" Margin="10,10,10,0">
                                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Photo}" Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Image>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Fill" MinimumHeightRequest="400" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding FName}" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"></Label>

                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the color of a selected item on a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490004/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-a-selected-item-on-a-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Android renderer for view cell and override GetCellCore method. Sample code below:

```
public class CustomViewCellRenderer:ViewCellRenderer
{
    public CustomViewCellRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context)
    {
         var cell= base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);
        if (parent is Android.Widget.ListView listView)
        {
            listView.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
            listView.CacheColorHint = Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent;

        }
        return cell;
    }

    protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, this works, but it only works while the item is being selected, after it is selected it goes back to the orage

Comment: Got it working adding this to the cs:
private void ViewCell_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lastCell != null)
                lastCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
            var viewCell = (ViewCell)sender;
            if (viewCell.View != null)
            {
                viewCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                lastCell = viewCell;
            }
        }

Comment: Great... Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create an extended viewcell something like the following:

```
public class ExtendedViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedBackgroundColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("SelectedBackgroundColor", 
                            typeof(Color), 
                            typeof(ExtendedViewCell), 
                            Color.Default);

    public Color SelectedBackgroundColor
    {
      get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedBackgroundColorProperty); }
      set { SetValue(SelectedBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Android custom renderer
As the cell is rendered, this one captures the current (unselected, default theme) colour of the Android view cell, and then sets the colour of the view-cell’s background whenever the IsSelected property of the Android view-cell changes from false to true. And then resets it to the originally captured colour when when it flips back.

Obviously this may get a little more complex if you need to select multiple items in your list, but this is as far as I needed to go for my solution.

```
assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedViewCell), typeof(ExtendedViewCellRenderer))]
namespace 
xamformsdemo.Droid.CustomRenderers
 {
   public class ExtendedViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
  {

private Android.Views.View _cellCore;
private Drawable _unselectedBackground;
private bool _selected;

protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, 
                                                  Android.Views.View convertView, 
                                                  ViewGroup parent, 
                                                  Context context)
 {
   _cellCore = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

  _selected = false;
  _unselectedBackground = _cellCore.Background;

  return _cellCore;
}

protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
  base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, args);

  if (args.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
  {
    _selected = !_selected;

    if (_selected)
    {
      var extendedViewCell = sender as ExtendedViewCell;
      _cellCore.SetBackgroundColor(extendedViewCell.SelectedBackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
    }
    else
    {
      _cellCore.SetBackground(_unselectedBackground);
    }
   }
  }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm accomplishing this with no custom renderers needed at all in my app and here's how:

my **style.xml** file (put it in Resources/values folder and with AndroidResource build action):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <color name="FancyCyanColorOfMine">#00ffff</color>
  <style name="Theme.Main" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/FancyCyanColorOfMine</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And then I'm using the theme like this over my MainActivity declaration:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Main", [OTHER STUFF OF YOURS])]
public sealed class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
...
}
```

There are lots of other tags for colored things like that "colorActivatedHighlight" which you can track down in Android documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr, maybe just search for the word "color"