# Getting red background for the listView's context actions when trying to delete a cell/Item from the listview in Xamarin forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Unable to remove the red background color from the listview while deleting the Item from ListView in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem? A screenshot will be helpful.

Comment: seems like a task for a custom renderer, but as @AndroDevil said if you post a screenshot we can help you in more detail

Comment: I think you mean [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490004/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-a-selected-item-on-a-listview/32513979#32513979)

Comment: Can you add more detail about your problem? Your question is not so clear.