# Set the background color of selected listview item from custom list Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom ListView and a custom ViewCell for a Xamarin Forms project with iOS and android. I created the custom listView so that my list could alternate colors (which is pretty much successful). Unfortunately when I created the custom ListView it stopped highlighting the selected cell so thats why I created the custom ViewCells.

I'm having trouble with the android side of things. I can change the color when the cell is selected. But I'm not sure how to change the color back once another cell is selected.

Here's my CustomList class ...

```
public class CustomList : ListView
{
    public CustomList (){}

    protected override void SetupContent(Cell content, int index)
    {
        base.SetupContent (content, index);
        var currentCell = content as ViewCell; 

        currentCell.View.BackgroundColor = index % 2 == 0 ? Color.FromRgb (235, 235, 235) : Color.FromRgb (255, 255, 255); 
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward, just sets the color based on the index. (Maybe theres something else I can add in here to handle the selected cell?)

Heres the CustomCell class :

```
public class CustomCell : ViewCell
{
    public const String isSelectedProperty = "IsSelected"; 

    public CustomCell ()
    {
    }
}
```

and in the iOS Renderer:

```
public class CustomCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    private UIView view; 


    public CustomCellRenderer ()
    {
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell (item, reusableCell, tv); 

        if (view == null) {
            view = new UIView (cell.SelectedBackgroundView.Bounds);
            view.Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB (128, 204,255).CGColor;  
        }
        cell.SelectedBackgroundView = view; 
        return cell; 
    }
}
```

and the android renderer:

```
public class CustomCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    public CustomCellRenderer ()
    {
    }

    protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCellCore (item, convertView, parent, context);
        return cell;
    }

    protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnCellPropertyChanged (sender, e);
        var customCell = sender as CustomCell; 
        if (e.PropertyName == CustomCell.isSelectedProperty) {
            customCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb (128, 204, 255); 
        } 

    }
}
```

So the iOS part works. And the android part 'works' as in it selects the color of the cell but the color stays. I want only the selected cell to have a different background color. Any ideas?

Comment: So you mean to say you have 3 colours. 2 for the alternating list items and 1 if any of them is selected?@Shane

Comment: @AkashAmin Yes, thats correct. The iOS part works but I can't find a method similar to `cell.SelectedBackgroundView` for android. What I have for android works also but it just changes the color of the cell all together and doesn't change back when its not selected

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25887514/833197) SO answer can point you in the right direction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms ListView: Set the highlight color of a tapped item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885238/xamarin-forms-listview-set-the-highlight-color-of-a-tapped-item)

Answer (score 1):

For Android, in the styles.xml in the custom theme definition i have set:

```
<item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/color_coloredbackground</item>
<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/color_coloredbackground</item>
<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/color_coloredbackground</item>
```

And this solves my selected background color in any listview. I guess that could help you.