# Xamarin.Forms ListView change Cell on ContextMenu open

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, listviewitem

I use Xamarin.Forms to define a `ListView`. This `ListView` defines some `ContextAction`s on inside the `ViewCell`. Depending on the platform, these context actions are then presented to the user. In Android, this is triggered by long-pressing the specific item. Sadly, this Item will not be (properly) highlighted, as can be seen in this screenshot (I long-pressed *Third Item*, sadly I can't yet embed images).

[image]

**Is there a way to modify the Cell when the context menu opens?** Specifically asking for a solution for Android, but a general answer is welcome as well. The goal eventually is to improve highlighting, e.g. by changing the cell's background color. Modifying the cell, when one `ContextAction` is pressed, is not what I am looking for.

I browsed through the source code of Xamarin.Forms and thought about somehow inheriting from e.g. the ViewCell class, but couldn't find an event or command that would be triggered / called upon long-pressing an item. I have set up a simple repository to which illustrates the behavior: [GitHub repository](https://github.com/maddin25/soq_listview_customCell)

**The most important code snippets**

- ListView definition in XAML

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewContextMenu" x:Class="ListViewContextMenu.ListViewContextMenuPage">
      <ListView x:Name="MyListView">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                      <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                          <MenuItem Text="Action" Command="{Binding OnAction}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                      </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                      <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                  </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
  </ContentPage>
  ```
- MyItem definition (MVVM)

  ```
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using Xamarin.Forms;

  namespace ListViewContextMenu
  {
      public class MyItem
      {
          public string Name { get; set; }
          public Command OnAction { get; set; }

          public MyItem()
          {
              OnAction = new Command((obj) => Debug.WriteLine($"Item {obj.ToString()} clicked"));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Identifying when the longpress gesture has happened is probably a good way to do this. Have you looked at how Xlabs detected LongPress? https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=longpress

Comment: You can use a Customrenderer or Effects to handle the item longpress manually ex: Control.ItemLongClick += Control_ItemLongClick; where you customize the look and feel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for custom renderer - you can simply add following tag(s) to `styles.xml` (location: *Android project > Resources > values > styles.xml*)

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
</style>
<color name="ListViewHighlighted">#A8A8A8</color>
```

More details can be found at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38457882/7292772).

[image]