# Xamarin.Forms iOS listview selected item color

Tags: c#, ios, listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I need to change the selected item color of a listview in my Xamarin.Forms app.
So I created a custom renderer...

PCL C#:

```
public class DarkViewCell : ViewCell {}
```

PCL XAML:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <local:DarkViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          ... Stuff ...
        </ViewCell.View>
      </local:DarkViewCell>            
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

iOS

```
public class DarkViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    private UIView bgView;

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

        cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        cell.TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;

        if (bgView == null)
        {
            bgView = new UIView(cell.SelectedBackgroundView.Bounds);
            bgView.Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(48,48,48).CGColor;
            bgView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.FromRGB(48, 48, 48).CGColor;
            bgView.Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
        }

        cell.SelectedBackgroundView = bgView;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

But is not working. I also tried to change the SelectionStyle but nothing...

**EDIT**

In a new project it works. And the code is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but, I removed

```
<x:Arguments>
    <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
</x:Arguments>
```

and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableView tv)
{
    var cell = base.GetCell(item, tv);
    cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView() { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black };
    return cell;
}
```

**Update:**
I just used your code in a dummy project and it works as it should. Did you add the assembly attribute to register the custom renderer?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DarkViewCell), typeof(DarkViewCellRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS
{
    public class DarkViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is anything else in the custom renderer working or is it not working at all? I just copied that piece of code over from one of my own projects where it works exactly as needed.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Assembly attribute is there, breakpoints work as expected. I'm using the simulator could it be a bug? What are you using?

Comment: Also the simulator. You could try removing the <ViewCell.View> tags, they're unnecessary but I doubt that will fix it.

Comment: There is this line in the documentation as well: "For most Xamarin.Forms elements, it is optional to provide a custom renderer in each platform project. If a custom renderer isn't registered, then the default renderer for the control's base class will be used. However, custom renderers are required in each platform project when rendering a ViewCell element." - Do you also have an Android renderer for it if you have an Android platform project?

Comment: No fix removing ViewCell.View

Comment: Android protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
        {
            return base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);
        }

Comment: UWP public override Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetTemplate(Cell cell)
        {
            return base.GetTemplate(cell);
        }

Comment: On a real device I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently, I found the best way to set the background color of a cell is to use the cells `ContentView`

Try using the following in your `GetCell` method

```
cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code it's working for me

```
 public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableView tv)
  {
    var cell = base.GetCell(item, tv);

     cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView {
     BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray,
   };
  return cell;
 }
```

Below link is useful for you

[Xamarin.Forms ListView: Set the highlight color of a tapped item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885238/xamarin-forms-listview-set-the-highlight-color-of-a-tapped-item)