# Xamarin.Forms ListView selected item color (non-global, using a custom renderer)

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

By default the selected item color in a Xamarin.Forms ListView is orange.

[image: Selected Color ListView]

As [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885238/xamarin-forms-listview-set-the-highlight-color-of-a-tapped-item) posts already point out, you can change this globally by adding this line to your `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/accent</item>
```

Or write some fix that sets the cell's background color using Xamarin.Forms (which in my eyes is a bit of a hack, I rather find a native solution).

I would really like to know if its also possible with a custom renderer (so they can be set independently).

*Note: I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754721/3571997), however it resulted in multiple cells appearing as selected.*

Comment: What if you set color to white and have ViewCell with grid inside and set grid background color depending on selected item?