# Xamarin Forms Listview Rounded Corner Cell highlight grayout

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm finding a solution to customize on-tap listview cell grayout with rounded corners

**This is what I'm having now But I need to make the greyout as the next image**

[image: This is what I'm having now But I need to make the greyout as the next image]

**This is what I'm expecting!!!
[image: This is what I'm expecting!!!]

```
<ListView ItemSelected="ItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}" SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <custom:RoundedCornerView RoundedCornerRadius="12" Margin="11,5.5,11,5.5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="11" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding WardName}".../>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </custom:RoundedCornerView>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Well, I have a question what exactly are you trying to do I mean do you want that when you click your listview the Selected Item colour change should have rounded borders? I mean I don't understand

Comment: @G.hakim Yes, *only* the custom:RoundedCornerView view should get highlighted (instead of the whole view cell of the the listview)

Comment: So you will have to make changes in a couple of things I will update the answer in sometime

Comment: You need a ViewCell custom Renderer to remove the default selection color or change it to whatever color you want. After that, add a TapGestureRecognizer and change the background color of the box view onclick

Comment: @DuminduDeSilva - Can you show `custom:RoundedCornerView` to know about the available events of it.

Comment: @Arvindraja please go through https://drive.google.com/open?id=10wC2ZLn5LFQoBydWnY38tsiW4UUPVLvlp7JozQWiVj8. Thank you

Comment: @DuminduDeSilva - Check my answer here, it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885238/xamarin-forms-listview-set-the-highlight-color-of-a-tapped-item/53079812#53079812

Comment: @Arvindraja thank you.  In here the color is not changing because the we are trying to change a color inide a listview which is made using a OberverableCollection. But I managed to sort it out using DynamicReources. The thing is the tap event triggers once the finger moved up. I need to trigger it once the finger pressed

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a BackgroundColor property for the custom:RoundedCornerView. You can have a binding property assigned to the BackgroundColor.

eg: `<custom:RoundedCornerView RoundedCornerRadius="12" BackgroundColor= {Binding CellColor} Margin="11,5.5,11,5.5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >`

In your model class which is binded for this ListView, you can have this property (assume that you used INotifyPropertyChanged in the model class.

```
    private string cellColor = "#ffffff";
public string CellColor
{
get { return cellColor;}
set { cellColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("CellColor");}
}
```

In the ViewModel, you can have an ICommand for triggering the tap of the list item click. In the method associated with the ICommand, you have code to change the color of the CellColor property of that particular list item to grey color.

Comment: Thanks For the Answer. In here the color is not changing because the we are trying to change a color inide a listview which is made using a OberverableCollection. But I managed to sort it out using DynamicReources. The thing is the tap event triggers once the finger moved up. I need to trigger it once the finger pressed.