# Collection view selected item color is set as Gray not Transparent in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, collectionview

I am using the latest xamarin forms version because in the previous version I am facing the issue in the collection view when I selected the item the selected item color set as gray if I set the background as Transparent. I upgraded the new version ( https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/14672 they mentioned it was fixed in the latest version) but I am getting the same issue in the latest version also.

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" 
                                    Value="Transparent" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout Margin="20">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    SelectionMode="Single" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                           Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60" 
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding Location}"
                           FontAttributes="Italic" 
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Anyone please suggest any workaround for this. My requirement is to set the background as Transparent for selected Item in xamarin iOS

Comment: As a test, please set to "Red" instead of Transparent - does that work?

Comment: You can try to use the custom renderer or the FlowListView nuget. If you need more information, you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60041116/xamarin-forms-collectionview-cannot-give-selecteditem-transparent-background).